# paragraph hides behind preceding relative div, how do I get it to clear below?

Tags: javascript, html, css, position

I've created a button which looks like it slides a section out from behind another section. Exactly what I intended (though I haven't finished styling).

However, now the subsequent elements which are supposed to be down the page, are hiding behind that element. I feel like I accomplished something interesting, but then this problem, which seems basic to me, is messing it up.

How do I get the paragraph below it to show up down the page instead of behind it. I'm kind of at a loss, please help!

codepen link: https://codepen.io/lherron/pen/qBNyNga

```js
 const lukeCustOpen = document.querySelector('.lukeCustOpen');

  function lukeCustomOpen() {
    togOpen();
    shiftLeft();
    shiftRight();
  }

  function lukeCustomClose() {
    togClose();
    unShiftLeft();
    unShiftRight();
  }

  function togOpen() {
    var x = document.querySelector(".tog-one");
    if (!x.classList.contains("slide")) {
      x.classList.add("slide");
    } else {
      console.log("doesnt");
    }
  }

  function togClose() {
    var x = document.querySelector(".tog-one");
    if (x.classList.contains("slide")) {
      x.classList.remove("slide");
    } else {
      console.log("error");
    }
  }

  function shiftLeft() {
    var x = document.querySelector(".col-one");
    if (!x.classList.contains("shift-left")) {
      x.classList.add("shift-left");
    } else {
      console.log("already shifted left");
    }
  }

  function unShiftLeft() {
    var x = document.querySelector(".col-one");
    if (x.classList.contains("shift-left")) {
      x.classList.remove("shift-left");
    } else {
      console.log("already un-shifted");
    }
  }

  function shiftRight() {
    var x = document.querySelector(".col-two");
    if (!x.classList.contains("shift-right")) {
      x.classList.add("shift-right");
    } else {
      console.log("already shifted right");
    }
  }

  function unShiftRight() {
    var x = document.querySelector(".col-two");
    if (x.classList.contains("shift-right")) {
      x.classList.remove("shift-right");
    } else {
      console.log("already un-shifted");
    }
  }

  function buttonShift() {
    var x = document.querySelector(".button-pos-static");
    if (!x.classList.contains("button-shift")) {
      x.classList.add("button-shift");
    } else {
      console.log("already shifted");
    }
  }

  function unButtonShift() {
    var x = document.querySelector(".button-pos-static");
    if (x.classList.contains("button-shift")) {
      x.classList.remove("button-shift");
    } else {
      console.log("already un-shifted");
    }
  }
  lukeCustOpen.addEventListener('click', lukeCustomOpen);
```

```css
.column {
  float: left;
  padding-top: 20px;
  width: 50%;
  height: 300px;
}

.row {
  position: relative;
  padding-left: 2%;
}

.row:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}

.col-one,
.col-two,
.tog-one {
  -webkit-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
  -ms-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
  transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
}

.col-one {
  position: absolute;
  left: 25%;
  background-color: tan;
  z-index: 5;
}

.shift-left {
  left: 10% !important;
}

.col-two {
  position: absolute;
  left: 75%;
  width: 25%;
  z-index: 1;
}

.shift-right {
  left: 60% !important;
  width: 33%;
}

.button-pos-static {
  position: relative;
  left: 20%;
}

.button-shift {
  left: 25% !important;
}

.tog-one-wrapper {
  position: absolute;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.tog-one {
  position: relative;
  left: -105%;
  margin-top: 40%;
  padding: 1%;
  height: 100px;
  width: 98%;
  background-color: white;
  border: 3px solid grey;
}

.slide {
  left: 0% !important;
}

.tog-one-close {
  position: absolute;
  top: 15px;
  right: 15px;
  display: block;
  max-width: 15px;
  max-height: 15px;
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
  z-index: 3;
  font-family: helvetica;
  color: rgb(85, 74, 75);
  background-color: transparent;
  background-image: url("https://serge.org/wp-content/uploads/x-icon.png");
  filter: invert(50%) brightness(100%);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 15px;
  border: none;
  transform: rotate(0deg);
  transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
}

.tog-one-close:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
  transform: rotate(90deg);
}

a.srgLH-button4,
a.soActionBtn {
  color: white;
  background-color: rgba(239, 96, 74, 1);
  font-weight: 600;
  font-family: Open Sans;
  font-size: 12pt;
  border-radius: 2px;
  padding: 10px 20px 10px 20px;
  margin: 10px 20px 10px 20px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 0 transparent;
  transition: 0.3s;
}

a.srgLH-button4:hover,
a.soActionBtn:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
  color: rgb(239, 96, 74);
  box-shadow: 2px 5px 9px 4px rgb(47, 36, 26, 0.1);
  background-color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">

  <title>Give Section Slider-Tab</title>

  <style>

  </style>
</head>

<body>

  <div class="row">
    <div class="column col-one"></div>

    <div class="column col-two">
      <div class="tog-one-wrapper">
        <a class="srgLH-button4 lukeCustOpen">Give Now</a>
        <div class="tog-one">This is tog-one<button class="tog-one-close" onclick="lukeCustomClose()">&nbsp;</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
  <p>
    Curabitur cursus tempus enim, a feugiat odio vestibulum eget. Fusce vitae turpis vitae quam lacinia maximus. Morbi risus tortor, malesuada eget lacinia et, rutrum in enim. Curabitur feugiat malesuada aliquet. Suspendisse consequat risus sem, quis dictum eros feugiat in.
  </p>
</body>
<script type="text/javascript">
 
</script>

</html>
```